# Tailwind safelist not allowing any colour

Tags: tailwind-css

I have an issue with tailwind, I have added a pattern to allow the use of any colour, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
`safelist: [
    "text-[#e83e8c]",
    "text-[#fed216]",
    "text-[#60d394]",
    "text-[#d3d4d3]",
    { pattern: /^text-\[#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}\]$/ },
],`
```

The first 4 text colours work fine, but the pattern does not tried multiple iterations of the pattern but none of which work until I manually specify the colour,

Any advice?